# Cannot understand why IDLE gui is not returning the values that the author is saying it should return

Tags: python

I am reading the book Learning Python and the author provides these two snippets of code, he then runs "abc" like so permute1("abc") and this returns all the permutations of abc, when I do it in IDLE. It returns ['abc']. I don't understand how the author is saying that it should return ['abc', 'acb' -- etc ]
What am I missing here?

```
def permute1(seq):
    if not seq:
        return [seq]
    else:
        res = []
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
            for x in permute1(rest):
                res.append(seq[i:i+1] + x)
            return res

def permute2(seq):
    if not seq:
        yield seq
    else:
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]
            for x in permute2(rest):
                yield seq[i:i+1] + x
```

Comment: the easiest: Use `itertools.combinations` or `itertools.permutations` or `itertools.product`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you added an extra indentation to the `return res` line in your first for loop.

This is making your function terminate early. After we unindent that `permute1("abc")` works as expected.

Comment: Can you help me understand the recursion portion of this at for x in permute1(rest): ?
I'm lost on what it is doing at that point. Does it go back through permute1? I'm confused on why this wouldn't infinitely loop?

Comment: `rest = seq[:i] + seq[i+1:]` removes the `i`th element from `seq` with each recursive call. Since `seq` is getting progressively shorter, it eventually ends up empty. An empty string or list (ie, `""` or `[]`) has a False value. So the recursion terminates at the `if not seq` statement.

I suggest you work through a call to `permute1("ab")` line-by-line on paper and using http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit . Good luck!